# How can I manipulate this substitution of variables?

Tags: calculus

I am struggling with the fourth of these [midterm practice problems:](https://math.berkeley.edu/~giventh/mt2_2015_samples.pdf)

> Express the derivative $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}$ of the composite function obtained from a twice differentiable function $f(x, y)$ by the substitution $x = u + v$, $y = uv$.

I am unsure on how this substitution helps (although I have no doubt it does), and I can't think of valid manipulations to get a correct result.

My best guess is:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = u \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$$

$$\therefore \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v} = uv\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}$$

Assuming the way you do the chain rule is do it for each parameter then sum the results together, but I am unsure if this valid. Feels weird though, this would imply that:

$$uv\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v} = 0$$

which I've definitely seen equations where they look like this, but I am skeptical... Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + u\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u\partial v} = \frac{\partial }{\partial u}\left(
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + u\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\right)=
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + u\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\right)+\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + u\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\right)=\quad
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x}+
\left(\frac{\partial u }{\partial x}
+v\frac{\partial u }{\partial y}\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
+
(u+v)\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}
+vu \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=\qquad
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x}+
(u+v)\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}
+vu \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}
$$
where $$\frac{\partial u }{\partial x}
+v\frac{\partial u }{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u }{\partial v}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(u,v) = f(x,y) = f(u+v, uv)$. Then $$\frac {\partial g} {\partial v} = \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} u ,$$ so $$\frac {\partial ^2 g} {\partial u \partial v} = \frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial x^2} + \frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial y \partial x} v + \frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial x \partial y} u + \frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial x^2} u v = \frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial x^2} + (u + v) \frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial x \partial y} + uv \frac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial x^2}$$.

(When you change variables, it is wise to also change the name of your function, or else you will quickly start making mistakes caused by the collision in notation, i.e. it is not wise to have both $f(x,y)$ and $f(u,v)$.)